# C# Sending Json body that includes a file

Tags: json, rest

I have a C# project that

- gets a request to do work
- performs the work
- returns to the api a json object containing the results of the request

This is working fine.  As the work is done there is a log file that gets populated with various information (date being processed, errors encountered, etc.).  I want to include a request type that would tell my program to return to the API the log file.  Because I want this to be "just another request" I am trying to figure out how to include the file as part of the json body being returned.  Is this possible?  Is there a way to include a file (actual file - not just the contents of the file) in the json body?

I know how to return the file as it's own post - is there a way to return a json AND a file in the same post or am I looking at 2 separate post requests?  One for the json body and a separate post that would send the file?

Comment: Just send a property as a byte[]... with the content of the file and on the other end write those bytes to a file

Comment: HTTP requests always have one and only one response body. Either bundle the file in the JSON (in a property as a serialized string for example), embeed the JSON in the file (more complicated to separate them) or make two separate requests.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I believe we are going to go with a separate endpoint which keeps things simple